# LibGdx OrthographicCamera translation

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to move camera to scroll into my game but nothing happens.

My code :

```
public class Terrain implements Screen {
 @Override
public void show() {
    widht = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, widht, height);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    render = new ShapeRenderer();
    render.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    render.setAutoShapeType(true);
    cam.update();}

 @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    processInput();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.929f, 0.819f, 0.772f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    render.begin();
    render.rect(0,50,1000,25);
    render.end();
    batch.end();



}

private void processInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        cam.translate(25,0);
        cam.update();


    }

}
```

When I I tap the screen nothing happens. If I view the position of the camera she moves well but the rectangle is still in the same place.

Any idea on my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `ShapeRenderer` defaults to the camera coordinates.

If you want to change this you'll need to set the projection matrix on the renderer to something else.

For example:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    processInput();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.929f, 0.819f, 0.772f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    // Switch to the batch instead of the default.
    render.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    render.begin();
    // Changed the size of the rectangle so it's easier to see.
    render.rect(100, 50, 100, 25);
    render.end();
    batch.end();
}
```

Now when you tap on the screen the rectangle will appear to move to the left until it is no longer visible.